# Is there a text-based way of generating Blender geometries?

Tags: modeling, import

I have been a happy user of [OpenSCAD](https://openscad.org/) for a while, and I've gotten to appreciate the fact that you can set and review measurements easily, keep track of versions, modify files programmatically.

Now I am in the process of switching some workflows to Blender, as rendering capabilities in OpenSCAD are limited, and would like to have the best of both worlds.

I have explored OpenSCAD importers, but they go through the STL export in OpenSCAD, so everything comes out as a single block.

I've also looked at [BlendSCAD](https://github.com/3DLIRIOUS/BlendSCAD) which looks interesting, but a bit raw around the edges, especially to one that isn't very familiar with Python yet.

So the question is - are there other ways to generate geometries via text input? I can totally handle everything else (colors, materials) via the UI, but for things such as rough-modeling a kitchen (mostly parallelepipeds as far as I'm concerned), I'd like to write things in a text file.

Comment: There isn't one that's any better than BlendSCAD.  If OpenSCAD can output obj files or other similar formats that blender can input, I would suggest doing the CAD in OpenSCAD and then exporting the file in a blender readable format.  You can import the result to blender and use it there. EDIT: I checked the OpenSCAD documents and it can export STL, so I would export STL files and import them into blender.

Comment: @MartyFouts - thanks, but unfortunately OpenSCAD exports everything as one single blob, no matter what, so any logical structure I built in the source goes lost (colors, for starters). I am trying BlendSCAD, but keep getting errors even running the demos: ``File "/home/simone/Downloads/blender-2.92.0-linux64/2.92/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/blendscad/__init__.py", line 74, in initns
    import blenderscad
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blenderscad'
``

Comment: will this fix work for you?https://copypaste.guru/WhereIsMyPythonModule/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-blendscad

Comment: @MartyFouts Nope - same problem. I installed blendscad both via the system pip and the blender pip but the problem is still there